# Stanford POS tagger with GATE twitter model is slow

Tags: java, performance, twitter, nlp, gate

I am using the [Stanford POS tagger](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tagger.shtml) with the [GATE Twitter model](https://gate.ac.uk/wiki/twitter-postagger.html) and the tagger takes around 3 seconds to initialize, is this normal or am I loading it incorrectly?

**Small sample code:**

```
package tweet.nlp.test;

import edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger;

public class TweetNLPTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String text = "My sister won't tell me where she hid my food. She's fueling my anorexia. #bestsisteraward #not ";

        MaxentTagger tagger = new MaxentTagger("models/gate-EN-twitter.model");

        String taggedText = tagger.tagString(text);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

> Reading POS tagger model from models/gate-EN-twitter.model ...
>   warning: no language set, no open-class tags specified, and no
>   closed-class tags specified; assuming ALL tags are open class tags
>   done [3.1 sec].
>
> My_PRP$ sister_NN won't_MD tell_VB me_PRP where_WRB
>   she_PRP hid_VBD my_PRP$ food._NN She's_VBZ fueling_VBG my_PRP$
>   anorexia._NN #bestsisteraward_HT #not_HT _HT  BUILD SUCCESSFUL
>   (total time: 3 seconds)

Comment: @Yasen I thought maybe I am not doing this right because the GATE model has a `.model` extension while the other models have a `.tagger` extension. That doesn't have to do with anything right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me it looks normal, it takes around 2 or 3 seconds to init. The `.tagger` is the same as the `.model`.

You can see it in the sample models provided by the Stanford Tagger :

```
model = wsj-0-18-bidirectional-nodistsim.tagger
```

Comment: Well, at least I found someone to give the rep to :P

Comment: Other thing, I don't really understand if you want to use the GATE API but if so you can create a new StanfordTaggerPR like that `pr =(LanguageAnalyser)Factory.createResource("gate.stanford.Tagger",params,features);`